# How does evaluate pointers and reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, pointers, multiple-inheritance, reinterpret-cast, memory-layout

I have the following code that I run in Visual Studio. The address of `c` is the same as the address to which points `pa` but not the same as `pb`. Yet both ternary operator will evaluate as `true`, which is what would have expected by only viewing the code and not see the pointed addresses for pa and `pb` in debugger.
The third ternary operator will evaluate as `false`.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() : m_i(0) {}

protected:
    int m_i;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() : m_d(0.0) {}

protected:
    double m_d;
};

class C
    : public A
    , public B
{
public:
    C() : m_c('a') {}

private:
    char m_c;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    A *pa = &c;
    B *pb = &c;

    const int x = (pa == &c) ? 1 : 2;
    const int y = (pb == &c) ? 3 : 4;
    const int z = (reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa) == reinterpret_cast<char*>(pb)) ? 5 : 6;

    std::cout << x << y << z << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How does this work?

Comment: Your question does not match the example code. You say "both ternary operators", but there are three. You say "if" but there isn't one.

Comment: What is the expected output of your program? What is the actual output?

Comment: @SebastianRedl: sorry third is also ternary. I have modified.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the actual output is 136. I would have expected to be 135 since pa=&c and pb=&c.

Comment: Comparing two pointers have two steps: 1) convert them to a common type (which may change the address they point to) and then 2) compare their address. With the `reinterpret_cast`, you skip the first step.

Comment: If you print out the actual addresses you will see that the difference between `pa` and `pb` happens to be equal to `sizeof(int)` which is the member in `A`. the pointer `pa` points to the `A` part of `c`, while `pb` points to the `B` part of `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pa` and `pb` are actually different. One way to test that is:

```
reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa) == reinterpret_cast<char*>(pb)
```

`pa == &c` and `pb == &c` both return `true`, but that does not mean the above must be `true`. `&c` will be converted to appropriate pointer type (`A*` or `B*`) via implicit pointer conversion. This conversion changes the pointer's value to the address of respective base class subobject of the object pointed-to by `&c`.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast):

> A prvalue pointer to a (optionally cv-qualified) derived class type can be converted to a prvalue pointer to its accessible, unambiguous (identically cv-qualified) base class. **The result of the conversion is a pointer to the base class subobject within the pointed-to object.** The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type.

(emphasis mine)

---

`A` is the first non-virtual base class of `C`, so it is placed directly at the beginning of `C`'s memory space, i.e.:

```
reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa) == reinterpret_cast<char*>(&c)
```

is `true`. But, `B` subobject is laid out after `A`, so it can not possibly satisfy the above condition. Both implicit conversion and `static_cast` then gives you the right address of the base subobject.

Answer (score 3):

A `C` instance has an `A` subobject and a `B` subobject.
Something like this:

```
    |---------|
    |---------|
    |    A    |
    |---------|
 C: |---------|
    |    B    |
    |---------|
    |---------|
```

Now,

```
A *pa = &c;
```

makes `pa` point to the location of the `A` subobject, and

```
B *pb = &c;
```

makes `pb` point to the location of the `B` subobject.

```
    |---------|
    |---------| <------ pa
    |    A    |  
    |---------|
 C: |---------| <------ pb
    |    B    |  
    |---------|
    |---------|
```

When you compare `pa` and `pb` to `&c`, the same thing happens - in the first case, `&c` is the location of the `A` subobject and in the second it's the location of the `B` subobject.
So the reason that they both compare equal to `&c` is that the expression `&c` actually has different values (and different types) in the comparisons.

When you `reinterpret_cast`, no adjustment takes place - it means "take the representation of this value and interpret it as representing a value of a different type".
Since the subobjects are in different locations, the results of reinterpreting them as locations of a `char` are also different.

Comment: Nice graphs. I think you forgot the C in the stack. That is, there is memory used also inside Class C.

Answer (score 1):

If you add some extra output, you can see what is going on;  I added the following line:

```
std::cout << "pa: " << pa << "; pb: " << pb << "; c: " << &c <<  std::endl;
```

The output of this will vary of course, since I am printing the values of the pointers, but it will look like:

```
pa: 0x1000 pb: 0x1008 c: 0x1000
```

The pb pointer is in fact pointing at pa + sizeof(int) (which on my 64 bit machine is 8 bytes).  This is because when you do:

```
B *pb = &c;
```

The compiler is casting the C object to a B, and will return you the value of the B variable.  The confusion is that your second ternary operator shows true.  This is (I am assuming) because the address of B is within the bounds of the address of C.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the address `pa` and `pb` pointing to directly, they're different because `A` and `B` are both base class of `C`, and `pa` is pointing to the base class subobject `A` of `c`, `pb` is pointing to the base class subobject `B` of `c`, the actual memory address will be different. They can't/shouldn't point to the same memory address.